# Do sub functions need save points?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm quite new to Oracle and PLSQL.  Just been reviewing some functions that have been created by other users.  From my understanding you do NOT need a save point if you are only doing select queries.  Save points are only required if you change data (Insert/Update/Delete).
But what happens in the case where you have two functions.  Function A and function B.
Function A - only calls function B
Function B - has an update statement.  Since we are updating this function will require a save point.

So my question is does function A require a save point as well?  Since it is calling function B?

Answer (score 1):

Savepoints are not required in Oracle. You can use them, but you are not obliged to do so. Regarding functions: if there's no commit or rollback issued in those functions or procedures, they are just part of the surrounding transaction.